# How is selectedSection.savedItems computed property modified twice?

Tags: ember.js

I am looping through saved items in my component template and I am getting the following error:

```
"Assertion Failed: You modified selectedSection.savedItems twice on <wc-app@model:plan-section::ember615:goal> in a single render. This was unreliable and slow in Ember 1.x and is no longer supported.
```

This is the code in the component template:

```
{{#each selectedSection.savedItems as |item index|}}
```

This is the savedItem computed property on the plan section model:

```
savedItems: Ember.computed('orderedItems.@each.isNew', function() {
    let itemsSaved = this.get('orderedItems').filter( (i) => !i.get('isNew'));
    return itemsSaved;
  }),
```

When there is 1 item or more this problem does not happen but when there are 0 items it causes this error.

How is this computed property modified twice?

Comment: What is your ember and ember-data version? There is a bug in ember-data 2.14 with links in async relationships

Comment: Hi Lux, thank you for your response. I upgraded to the latest version of ember and ember data and it fixed a different problem I was having:)

Comment: The latest version of ember-data (2.14) *has* this bug!